# Llamar animacion css a javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo un `div` que al hacerle click dispara el evento. Este evento debe tomar una animación de `css` (por *keyframes*). El problema es que al apretar el `div`, no me llama la regla del `css`.

```js
let sq = document.getElementById('square');
sq.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('click');
    setTimeout(up, 2000);

    function up() {
        sq.style.background = 'green';
    }
});
```

```css
#square {
    background: red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
    transition: down;
    transition-duration: 3s;
}

@keyframes down {
    0% {
        background: red;
    }

    50% {
        background: yellow;
        margin-top: 400px;
     }

    100% {
        background: orange;
        margin-top: 0px;
    }
}

#square2, #square3, #square4 {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
        <div id="square"></div>
        <div id="square2"></div>
        <div id="square3"></div>
        <div id="square4"></div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para lograr lo que quieres modifiqué la función `up` para asignar la propiedad `animation`.

```
function up(){
    //Para usar animaciones mediante @keyframes debes
    //usar la propiedad 'animation' y no 'transition'
    sq.style.animation = "down 3s linear";
}
```

Es código CSS

```
#square {
    background: red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
}

@keyframes down {
    0% {
        background: red;
    }

    50% {
        background: yellow;
        margin-top: 400px;
     }

    100% {
        background: orange;
        margin-top: 0px;
    }
}

#square2, #square3, #square4 {
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Gracias amigo!!